# How to change filename dynamically EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 differents files with two differents worksheet, i'm trying to retrieve data from one worksheet the other using the search by string (code below)

[image]

But the issue i'm facing is that the name of the folder and the name of the file can change depends on who opens it.

currently, i'm stuck here : `=INDEX('Z:\Jeremy\new test\[Fiche_Audit_-_V2__20210831.xlsx]Worksheet'!$3:$3;0;EQUIV("Nom";'Z:\Jeremy\new test\[Fiche_Audit_-_V2__20210831.xlsx]Worksheet'!$1:$1;0))`

I tried to put the name of the file "Fiche_Audit_-_V2__20210831.xlsx" in a cell and call the cell inside the formula like this : `=INDEX('Z:\Jeremy\new test\[";$E$2;"]Worksheet'!$3:$3;0;EQUIV("Tarif souscrit ";'Z:\Jeremy\new test\[";$E$2;"]Worksheet'!$1:$1;0))`

but it doesn't work.

I also tried `INDIRECT("E2")`, it doesn't work neither

The formula is in the file N°1 and the data is in the file N°2

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: INDIRECT needs the full string: `INDIRECT("'Z:\Jeremy\new test\["&$E$2&"]Worksheet'!$3:$3")` but realize that using INDIRECT requires the target workbook to be open or it will return a `#REF` error.